# background linear-gradient using currentColor sometimes wrong in IE (strange behavior)

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
background: linear-gradient(7deg, currentColor 50%, transparent 50%)
```

The color of the element is

[image]

As soon as you inspect the element in IE it reveals that the specificity war is won.

---

### .. But now comes the super strange part .. as soon as you inspect it the color flashes to the correct color .. Best test this in IE11 for yourself – The site is live [at www.cubesports.de](http://www.cubesports.de/fitness).

The wrong color only occurs on the **absolute positioned** `.devider`s

The issue occurs in EDGE aswell, but my browserstack somehow always reloads the page when I want hit "inspect element", so I can't tell if the strange crazy "fix" occurs here aswell.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gradient Generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

With it, that issue can be solved in IE ;)

Comment: And what exactly is causing this issue? Or better said: what exactly does fix it? I'm no friend of blindly pasting generated code.

Comment: Because just `background: linear-gradient` isn't sufficient to IE browsers. With that generator, you get the `-webkit-linear-gradient`, `-moz-linear-gradient` and `filter`

Comment: Sorry, should have said it: I use Autoprefixer. `filter` apparently is for IE6-9, which I don't care about. So I guess `filter` doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a reported and known bug with these browsers [see here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/1328019/).

Your best solution at present unfortunately is to avoid its use if you are looking to fully support IE 10 + as well as Edge.

Comment: The thing is: it works great, when not positioned absolute. If you can get your hand on an IE right now, maybe check www.cubesports.de/fitness and see for yourself. It is super strange. And why does it get applied once you inspect it?! This is nuts.

Comment: I would follow and report the bug in the provided link. However, I wouldn't get ahead of ourselves as it wouldn't be an overly popular/used property.